# Remote notification payload is null

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to integrate push notifications within my app. I've got handling remote notifications while the app is currently running working fine, however I'm trying to handle them when the app is not currently running using

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
 (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

however, it seems whenever I click the notification alert and it start up the app my notification payload is null.

I've used `NSLog` to log the payload and its showing that it is null.

Is there any reason it would be null? I know my notifications are setup right since they work within the app, but for some reason I cant figure this out. I've also logged the launchOptions and its showing null as well.

this is inside my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
NSDictionary *notificationPayload = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
NSLog(@"launch options: %@", launchOptions);
NSLog(@"payload: %@", notificationPayload);
```

Comment: Are you tapping on notification alert or app icon?  If the last case then this method will not be working

Comment: @nerowolfe tapping the alert, not the app icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a blog post about this a few years ago, and it's since changed in terms of where you set it up in Xcode.

But here's the blog post just in case, for some background information. http://runmad.com/blog/2010/06/debugging-executables-for-push-notifcations/

Now, in order to debug push notifications you need to edit the scheme.

You can change your target's launch settings in "Manage Scheme" to Wait for .app to be launched manually, which allows you debug by setting a breakpoint in `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and sending the push notification to trigger the launch of your app.

[image]

`application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` is a delegate method called when your app is currently active or comes to foreground.

It's important to test all 3 these scenarios thoroughly (from launch, from background, while active).

In the second method, you can check the app's state with

`[application applicationState] == UIApplicationStateActive`

and deal with the push notification accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see your payload information use following notification delegate method.And be sure that you have launch your app from notification center whenever you got notification, then only this method call.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    NSLog(@"userInfo: %@", userInfo);


    NSDictionary *dict=[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
    NSString *strPushMessege=[dict objectForKey:@"alert"];
    NSLog(@"strPushMessege %@",strPushMessege);
}
```

Comment: This method will fire only when app is in foreground.

Comment: If you click on notification this method will always call.You can see your all payload information.

Comment: From the Apple doc: If the app is running and receives a remote notification, the app calls this method to process the notification. Your implementation of this method should use the notification to take an appropriate course of action. For example, you could use it as a signal to connect to a server and download the data waiting that is waiting for the app.

Comment: Yes I know this but he is mentioned in his question that,If he clicks on notification he get null NSLog info.So to see Payload Info this could be good method that you can see your all payload Information.I have already mention that whenever you click notification this method will call.

Comment: Try to click on app icon for example when notification came, this method will be not fired

Comment: If you open your app from notification center this method will call not on app icon.